# Pyspark changes longs to ints

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Pyspark 1.2.1 with Hive. (Upgrading will not happen immediately).

The problem I have is that when I select from a Hive table, and add an index, pyspark changes long values to ints, so I end up with a temp table with a column of type Long, but values of type Integer. (See code below).

My question is: how can I either (a) perform the merge of the index (see code) without changing longs to ints; or (b) add the index in some other way that avoids the problem; or (c) randomize table columns without needing to join?

The underlying problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to randomize the order of certain columns in a hive table, and write that to a new table. This is to make data no longer personally identifiable. I'm doing that by adding an incrementing index to the original table and the randomised columns, then joining on that index.

The table looks like:

```
primary | longcolumn | randomisecolumn
```

The code is:

```
hc = HiveContext(sc)
orig = hc.sql('select * from mytable')
widx = orig.zipWithIndex().map(merge_index_on_row)
sql_context.applySchema(widx, add_index_schema(orig.schema()))
        .registerTempTable('sani_first')

# At this point sani_first has a column longcolumn with type long,
# but (many of) the values are ints

def merge_index_on_row((row, idx), idx_name=INDEX_COL):
    """
    Row is a SchemaRDD row object; idx is an integer;
    schema is the schema for row with an added index col at the end
    returns a version of row applying schema and holding the index in the new row
    """
    as_dict = row.asDict()
    as_dict[idx_name] = idx
    return Row(**as_dict)

def add_index_schema(schema):
    """
    Take a schema, add a column for an index, return the new schema
    """
    return StructType(sorted(schema.fields + [StructField(INDEX_COL, IntegerType(), False)],key=lambda x:x.name))
```

In the absence of a better solution, I'm going to force the affected columns to long type in the python code. This is...not great.